# Find count of no. of days and no. of event

Tags: r, optimization, calculated-columns, calc

Is it possible to calculate in r the number of days and count of b in var r from the following table:

```
id  r   s   t   u

1   a   100 1   27-06-2017

1   a   200 0   29-06-2017

1   b   300 0   01-07-2017

2   a   500 1   12-06-2017

3   b   100 0   02-07-2017

3   a   600 1   02-07-2017

4   a   200 0   12-06-2017

4   a   300 1   15-06-2017

4   b   200 0   18-06-2017

4   a   100 0   01-07-2017

5   a   200 0   04-06-2017
```

grouped by unique `ID` where the condition =   when  r = b, sum of s >= sum of s when t = 1?

Comment: Your condition is unclear for me, can you please elaborate on that

Comment: i have to identify the number of days it took for sum of s's when column r has b to be >= sum of s's when the column t has 1 in it. also the count of those events when they reach that condition

Comment: To give an example i want to know the number of days and times a person (ID) pays back money to me, wherein condition 1 in col t is where i give him money and b in col r is when he repays it to me.

Comment: Your condition is still very unclear. How can r (a character) be greater than the sum of s (which is a numeric). And what do you mean by sum of s if we are only considering one row?

Comment: s is the money that is transferred between me and different people, so when i pay him column t is 1 and when they repay it is shown as b in column r. col t and r are flags. a in column r is the money which i transferred to them without expecting it back. So, I want to know how long and after how many repayments do they cover my payment

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(new =  sum((r == "b") & s >= sum(s[t == 1])))
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do i get the count of days?